# gcc ld objdump. What tool should I use in order to have an the section of an object file having all three permissions read write and execute?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, object-files

I am using g++ on ubuntu. I compile some code and I need to unify the code section ".text" with the data section ".data" regarding a specific compilation unit ( object file ).

I already managed using directives like **attribute**((section(".mydata"))) to get both the compiled code and the global data defined into the same section, and I checked it with objdump.

I also managed to get it compiled, but afterwards a segment fault is issued when code is executed.

The problem is that this section should have execute write and read permissions, instead of "read and execute" or "read and write" that have the ".text" and ".data" sections respectively.

I suppose that using the  **attribute**((section(".tdata",someflags))) this should be possible, but until now I didn't find anything.

... update ...
I managed using the script bellow to create an object file as requested.

The main code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((section(".napl2")))
char s[]="testString";

__attribute__((section(".napl1")))
void nothingToDo(){
    printf("%s","doneNothing\n");
}

int main()
{ printf("%s\n",s);
    nothingToDo();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have the link script file bellow that is named "ldscript":

```
MEMORY {
  ERW_MEMORY(RWXA) : ORIGIN = 0xC000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}

SECTIONS{ 
  .napl : { 
        . = ALIGN(.);
    *(.napl1)
    *(.napl2)
    } > ERW_MEMORY
}
```

I compile using:

```
g++ -o Debug/test_object_file_section  -T ldscript main.cpp
```

I get:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: Debug/test_object_file_section has a LOAD
> segment with RWX permissions

doing

```
objdump -d -j .napl Debug/test_object_file_section
```

I get:

Debug/test_object_file_section:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .napl:

> 000000000000c040 <_Z11nothingToDov>:
> c040: 55                      push   %rbp
> c041: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
> c044: bf 3c c4 00 00          mov    $0xc43c,%edi
> c049: e8 52 01 00 00          call   c1a0 puts@plt
> c04e: 90                      nop
> c04f: 5d                      pop    %rbp
> c050: c3                      ret
> c051: 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
>
> 000000000000c058 :
> c058: 74 65 73 74 53 74 72 69 6e 67 00                    testString.

But I cannot still run the program as I get a

> (segmentation fault)

Any ideas ?